# Product and convex combination of two stochastic matrices

Tags: stochastic-processes, nonnegative-matrices, matrix-equations

Let $K_1$ and $K_2$ be two $N \times N$ stochastic matrices (hence non-negative and rows adding up to one) with zeros on the diagonal.  If $\alpha \in (0,1)$, is it possible to have

$$K_1 K_2 = \alpha K_1 + (1-\alpha)K_2?$$

Comment: Let $K_1 = K_2 = 11^*/N$, where $1$ denotes a vector of ones. But this is probably not what you have in mind.

Comment: Thanks Steve.  If I understand your notation, this does not quite fit my problem.  I need the diagonal entries to be zero.  My understanding is that the matrices you suggest have 1/N in the diagonal.

Comment: It can be done with $\alpha=1$.

Comment: If I understand my computer algebra system correctly (not necessarily true), this is not possible for $N=3$. If negative entries are allowed, it is clearly possible.

Comment: Thanks Gerry.  Unfortunately, $\alpha$ is less than one.  Steve: I agree.  I have enough restrictions that I can verify that for $N=3$ this is not possible.  Negative entries are not allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $$A=\pmatrix{0&.5&0&0&.5\cr.5&0&.5&0&0\cr0&.5&0&.5&0\cr0&0&.5&0&.5\cr.5&0&0&.5&0\cr}{\rm\ and\ }B=\pmatrix{0&0&.5&.5&0\cr0&0&0&.5&.5\cr.5&0&0&0&.5\cr.5&.5&0&0&0\cr0&.5&.5&0&0\cr}$$ Then $AB=.5A+.5B$.

Comment: Thanks Gerry!  If you know of any examples with non-symmetric matrices and/or different spectra (I believe these two matrices have the same set of eigenvalues), please let me know.  This is already pretty useful.

Comment: Ariel: If $AB=sA+tB$ for some matrices $A$ and $B$ and nonzero numbers $s$ and $t$, then $(A/s-I)(B/t-I)=I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, so that the matrices $A/s-I$ and $B/t-I$ are inverse to each other. Thus, necessarily $A$ and $B$ share the same set of Jordan chains. In particular, $AB=BA$. Also, for each $\lambda$ in the spectrum of $A$ there is some $\mu$ in the spectrum of $B$ such that $(\lambda/s-1)(\mu/t-1)=1$, and vice versa. This may have to do with Gerry's $A$ and $B$ having the same spectra.

Comment: Gerry: Can you provide details on how you found your matrices $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @Iosif, let $C$ be the permutation matrix representing the 5-cycle $(12345)$ in $S_5$. Then $2A=C+C^4$, $2B=C^2+C^3$, and $(C+C^4)(C^2+C^3)=(C+C^4)+(C^2+C^3)$ because $C^5=1$.

Comment: Thank you Gerry. Your solution is very clever and educational to me.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**: Federico Poloni points out that this fails to satisfy one of the criteria in the original posting in that this does not give a *non-trivial* convex combination of the two matrices.

Set
$$
K_1=\begin{pmatrix}0&\tfrac 12&0&\tfrac 12\\
\tfrac 12&0&\tfrac 12&0\\
0&\tfrac 12&0&\tfrac 12\\
\tfrac 12&0&\tfrac 12&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
K_2=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then $K_2K_1=K_1$.

I think of $K_2$ as a rotation of the square by $\pi$ and $K_1$ as a Markov transition to one of your neighbours on the square. Then $K_2K_1$ is a Markov transition to one neighbour, followed by a flip that sends you to the opposite neighbour.

Comment: The question explicitly disallows trivial convex combinations.

Comment: So it does... back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal{D}_n$ denote the set of doubly stochastic matrices. Then via a simple optimization routine, we can find several **numerical** examples. For instance,

\begin{equation*}
 K_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
  0 &    0 &    0&   1\\
  0 &    0 &    1&   0\\
  1 &    0 &    0&   0\\
  0 &    1 &    0&   0
\end{bmatrix},\qquad K_2=\text{argmin}_{K_2\in \mathcal{D}_n}\|K_1K_2-\alpha K_1 - (1-\alpha)K_2\|.
\end{equation*}
For instance, I used the following [CVX](http://cvxr.com/) code:

```
 n=4; % k1 = set as above
 cvx_begin
  variable k2(n,n)
  minimize norm(k1*k2-0.3*k1-0.7*k2)
  subject to
   k2 >= 0
   sum(k2,2)==ones(n,1)
   sum(k2,1)==ones(1,n)
 cvx_end
```

I obtained an objective value of $\sim 3\times 10^{-9}$. You can experiment with this code to construct several other examples, including perhaps more rational looking ones.

Comment: These examples fulfill asymmetry and different spectra too.

Comment: Does this guarantee zeros on the diagonal of $K_2$?

Comment: aargh, I oversaw that. That is indeed a decisive constraint!

Comment: and with this constraint,  I think a matrix of the form that I have above **won't** work! Thanks for pointing out